# Is there a way I can include my files in C++?

Tags: c++

Sorry super noob question. I'm new to C++ and any sort of programming in general but I created these programs to read user input and then read what command and file it is. I want to include file a.h but I'm having trouble with it. It's telling me my function main is redefined but when I take it out it spits out more errors. I'm considering maybe an if else statement? Any advice to get me going?

**File name tryout.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "a.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string cmd,command,file1,file2;
cout << "prompt<<";
cin >> cmd;
int len = cmd.length();

int temp = cmd.find('<');
command = cmd. substr(0,temp);
cout << "COMMAND: " << command << "\n";

cout << "File Redirection: " << cmd.at(temp) << "\n";

int temp1 = cmd.find('>');
file1 = cmd.substr(temp+1,temp1-temp-1);
cout << "FILE: " << file1 << "\n";

cout << "File Redirection: " << cmd.at(temp1) <<"\n";

file2 = cmd.substr(temp1+1, len-1);
cout << "File: " << file2 <<"\n";

return 0;
}
```

**File name "a.h"**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

string cmd,command1,command2,command3;
cout << "prompt<<";
cin >> cmd;
int len = cmd.length();

int temp = cmd.find('|');
command1 = cmd.substr(0,temp);
cout << "COMMAND: " << command1 << "\n";

cout << "PIPE: " << cmd.at(temp) << "\n";

command2 = cmd.substr(temp+1,len-1);
cout << "COMMAND: " << command2 << "\n";

cout << "PIPE: " << cmd.at(temp) << "\n";

command3 = cmd.substr(temp+2,len-2);
cout << "COMMAND: " << command3 << "\n";



return 0;
}
```

Comment: In which way is this error message unclear for you. You actually have a definition of `main()` in your header file. What do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I hesitate to suggest this has the very strong aroma of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I think you meant `<string>` instead of `<string.h>`

Answer (score 1):

The ".h" suffix is for a "header" file. If you think of a form letter, say from your cell company, at the top is a bunch of stuff telling you the company name, contact, etc.

A "header file" in C++ is a file that mostly provides definitions, things that you might need to share between multiple ".cpp" files. A ".cpp" file is generally a "compilation unit", a discrete file that the compiler is expected to turn into a similarly named "object file".

So in what you've shown us your division of interest is wrong. You've actually *implemented* main in the ".h" file.

When the compiler reads your ".cpp" file, it reads in the `iostream` and `string.h` headers, and *then* it reads in `a.h`, which includes an *implementation* of `main`. Then, it returns to processing `tryout.cpp` where it sees *another* implementation of `main`.

Solution: Remove main from `a.h`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple main() functions. When compiling, the C++ complier will take the content of the header files and add them where your #include statement is. If it finds more than one main() function, it does not know where to set the start point for the executable. You will have to rename the header file function to something else. Also note that it is common practice not to include function definitions in header files, rather than to use function declarations and have the definitions in other .cpp or pre-compiled .lib files.

I have found [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) article to be helpful for learning about how headers work.

Comment: It maybe noteworthy that this applies for other function definitions as well.

Comment: Correct, thank you for the addition. However, I do believe that this most often happens when main() is accidentally declared twice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two main functions. If you want to include your file you should put everything in a function or better build a class.